# Return true only if a sequence of bits are present

Tags: python, hex, bit-shift

the problem is as following.

I have a 16-bit register on an embedded system. What each bit represents is not of great importance to my question so I will leave that out.

I have a value that I can fetch from the system that is for example: `0x3540` and want to know if the hex corresponding to `0x3040` is set in that value. My first thought was that perhaps I could do the following:

`0x3540 & 0x3040`, but this is obviously problematic because I also have to check in the same hex if the sequence corresponding to `0x3140` is set. Using an & would mean that they are both true at the same time which they cannot be in reality. I realize why using logical `and` is incorrect, but what other way could I do it? Perhaps bit shifting of some sort?

Comment: Why can't they both be true at the same time? Isn't that like saying it's impossible for both "a" and "b" to be present in the string "ab"? Can you define in objective terms what "if the hex corresponding to X is set in Y" means?

Comment: `(value & 0x3040) == 0x3040`, if I understand your needs correctly. (i.e. "all the bits in 0xe3040 are present.")

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Check if bits of an integers are contained in another one](/q/66032572/90527)", "[How to determine if all set bits in one number is also set in another number?](/q/38927391/90527)"